# Dockerhub says Hello World causes CVE-2023-5363 and CVE-2023-5678

Tags: docker-compose, node.js, dockerhub, npm

Dockerhub says I have the vulnerabilities: CVE-2023-5363 and CVE-2023-5678, which is part of the openssl package.
See this image:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?  I've simplified my nodejs project to just `console.log('hello world');` and I removed all possible npm packages, but I still get this vulnerability.  My `hello` project only consists of 4 files and they are:

`~/src/index.js`

```
console.log('hello');
```

`~/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

`~/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api_image:
    image: johndev/api:test2
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./make.dockerfile
```

`~/make.dockerfile`

```
FROM node:21-alpine

WORKDIR /api

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN mkdir ./src
COPY ./src/ ./src/

RUN npm install
ENTRYPOINT [ "echo", "'All Done'" ]
```

To push an image to dockerhub, I just run these commands:

```
docker-compose up --build -d;
docker push johndev/api:test2;
```

What did I do wrong?  What in my code is causing the vulnerabilities CVE-2023-5363 and CVE-2023-5678?

Answer (score 1):

[CVS-2023-5363](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-5363) and [CVE-2023-5678](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-5678) are both vulnerabilities in OpenSSL. They don't come from any of the code that you wrote. Your base image - `node:21-alpine` - probably has a vulnerable version of OpenSSL by default. By adding the commands to update installed packages, you are installing a patched version of OpenSSL that no longer contains the vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to my `make.dockerfile`

```
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache openssl
```

So now my code looks like:

```
FROM node:21-alpine

WORKDIR /api
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache openssl

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN mkdir ./src
COPY ./src/ ./src/

RUN npm install
ENTRYPOINT [ "echo", "'All Done'" ]
```